# FTP Client issue

Tags: java, ftp, file-transfer, data-transfer

I'm having a tough time figuring something out. (I'm pretty new to all this.)
I wrote this java pgm to ftp a large file to a destination server.
Here's the code (codes been modified a bit for display):

```
public static void ftpUpload(String path, String upfileName, String dirName) throws Exception
{
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.addProtocolCommandListener((ProtocolCommandListener) new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    FileInputStream fis = null;

    int reply;

    try {
        client.connect(ftpserver);
        client.login(ftpuserid, ftppasswd);
        reply = client.getReplyCode();

        if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){
            client.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpdirectoryName + "/" + dirName);

            boolean mkDir = client.makeDirectory(getCurrentMMMYY().toLowerCase());

            client.changeWorkingDirectory(getCurrentMMMYY().toLowerCase());

              //Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
            fis = new FileInputStream(path + upfileName);

            //Store file to server
            client.storeFile(upfileName, fis);

        }    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            client.logout();
            //client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Something weird is happening on files I'm sending...
One of my files on the origination server is 82575786 in size, and when I ftp this file it almost sends the entire file. It actually sends 82574867. (missing 919)
Another file on the origination server is 717885, and when I ftp this file it almost sends the entire file. It actually sends 717522. (missing 363)

I pulled the log to see if something crashed, but it didn't show anything wrong with the transfer. Here are the 2 log entries showing the transfer.

[08/09/11 20:21:13:618 EDT] 00000043 SystemOut     O 221-You have transferred 717522 bytes in 1 files. 
221-You have transferred 82574867 bytes in 1 files.

Anyone's help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks
Dan.

Comment: may I ask why you have to use input AND outpustream, so whydoes sendfile only take one inputstream and it doesn't work? thx!

Answer (score 3):

Are you transferring in ASCII mode instead of binary?  ASCII mode converts CR/LF to LF and vice-versa depending on server and client settings.

Are you using [Apache's](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) FTP client?  It says the default is ASCII, you could try setting [BINARY_FILE_TYPE](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#BINARY_FILE_TYPE) with [setFileType](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType%28int%29):

```
client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, the file got a little further ahead by adding in the binary file type, but it still didn't ftp the entire file. Both files still didn't get the last couple of records.

Answer (score 1):

To upload a binary File you have to use the FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE but is not enough.

You are using only an INPUT stream, and you need to use an outputstream too

I hope that this example will help you:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect("192.168.30.20");
client.login("pwd", "pwd");

client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
String path_base = "/myPath/";
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("A.pdf");
OutputStream os = client.storeFileStream(path_base+ "B.pdf");


byte buf[] = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead = fis.read(buf);
while (bytesRead != -1) {
   os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
   bytesRead = fis.read(buf);}

fis.close();
os.close();
client.completePendingCommand();
client.logout();
client.disconnect();
```